# Recursive function to check if a graph is acyclic

Tags: python, recursion, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am a bit confused with using recursive functions in python.Below is my code in python that checks if a given set of points form an acylcic graph. The input format is as follows: the first two numbers in input consist of number of vertices and number of edges. The remaining numbers below represent vertices forming edges whose direction is from left number to right number. For example, check the image below
[image]

Below is my code that solves this problem. The output provides the number of cycles in the graph

```
#Uses python3

import sys

def acyclic(adj,cc,in_path):
    # check if value of ad
    global clock
    global cycles
    clock += 1
    for i in adj:
        for j in i:
            if visited[j] != 1:
                num = reach(adj,j,cc,in_path)

                if (0 not in visited):
                    return cc
                cc += 1

    return cc

def reach(adj,x,cc,in_path):
    visited[x] = 1
    # preVisit(x)
    global cycles
    cnum[x] = cc
    print(x)
    in_path.append(x)
    print(in_path)
    for i in adj[x]:
        print(adj[x])
        if visited[i] != 1:
            return reach(adj,i,cc,in_path)
        elif i in in_path:
            # print("in path")
            cycles += 1
            return (cycles)
            break
    # postVisit(x)
    # return visited[x]

def dfs(adj):
    global m
    global cycles
    # print(m)
    for i in range(n):
        in_path = []
        if visited[i] != 1:
            reach(adj,i,0,in_path)
    print (cycles)



def preVisit(x):
    global clock
    clock += 1
    prev[x] = clock
    # print("prev")
    # print(prev)


def postVisit(x):
    global clock
    clock += 1
    postV[x] = clock
    # print("post")
    # print(postV)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    cycles = 0
    clock = 0
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    data = list(map(int, input.split()))
    n, m = data[0:2]
    data = data[2:]
    edges = list(zip(data[0:(2 * m):2], data[1:(2 * m):2]))
    prev = [0 for _ in range(n)]
    postV = [0 for _ in range(n)]
    adj = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    cnum = [0 for i in range(n)]
    visited = [0 for i in range(n)]
    for (a, b) in edges:
        adj[a - 1].append(b - 1)
    print(adj)
    dfs(adj)
```

Whenever I use `return "reach(adj,i,cc,in_path)"` and `"return(cycles)"` in the function `reach()`, I get correct answers. However, taking them off gives me wrong answers. Can someone please explain me why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Regards,

Rishit

Comment: When you remove those lines, the function simply runs off the bottom and returns **None**.  BTW, note that you cannot reach the **break** statement, because you exit the function on the **return** line before.

Comment: If you're confused about recursion in this program, I strongly recommend that you go through a recursion tutorial of some sort; this is not an simple example from which to learn the concepts.

Comment: @Prune do you have any suggestions as to which would be good? I have been through some articles but there isn't enough clarity

Comment: I can't suggest specific resources without knowing your background, reading levels, learning styles, etc.  However, I recommend that you start with something simple, such as a factorial (**N!**) example, then Fibonacci, and then a **log n** sorting algorithm, such as merge sort or quick sort.